# How to convert css radial-gradient to javafx css radial gradient

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to know how to convert my rectangle radial-gradient (generated from Sketch) to javaFX. I do not understand the `radial-gradient()` constructor in the generated sketch CSS.

**Sketch Rectangle:**

[image]

**Generated CSS:**

```
background-image: radial-gradient(50% 108%, #40ADFF 50%, #1D94ED 100%);
border: 5px solid #1081D7;
box-shadow: 6px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
```

**JavaFx Rectangle:**
[image]

**JavaFX CSS:**

```
#myBtn{
    -fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 50%, #40ADFF 50%, #1D94ED 100%);
    -fx-border-color: #1081D7;
    -fx-border-width:  5px;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box , black , 4,1,6,2);
}
```